# How to suppress retries in Oracle Service Bus in case of no response

Tags: timeout, osb, oracle-service-bus

I am creating an OSB service which will contact a process and get back the response...

The problem is that the process may take varying amounts of time to respond to the request.

I have currently used retry count as 2.

In this case if the process takes a longer time to respond, the request times out and another request is sent to the process. All the while the process is still working on the first request . The osb service receives the response to the first request in the second or maybe third request.

So i want to set retry count as 2 in case of connection errors or application errors, but not in case of no response.

I can compromise on the part of application errors... But connection error needs to have retries..

Is there any way??

I searched in a lot of places... but in vain...

Comment: What about extending the connection timeout? How long could the process take? What transport are you using?

Comment: Yes! extending the timeout is an option.... But sometimes the request takes much more time than usual because of a complicated process involvement.. And i do not want it to send multiple requests under any circumstances... It uses the http transport... If this answers your questions....
Currently i have kept the retry counts as 0. But this also stops the connections errors from being retried...
@ErikO Thanks for the prompt reply...

Answer (score 1):

Try the Read Timeout parameter in the Business Service HTTP Transport Config. If i understand your problem correctly..this is the solution

Comment: the read timeout is the one that is causing the problem. when the read timeout is crossed, the osb sends another request. But the service will still return the response for the first request. this causes the service to receive multiple copies of same request.

Comment: have you set the retry count to 0? i experienced a similar issue, setting the retry count to 0 solved the issues the retry created.

Comment: yes!! that is the thing that i have done currently... But it has its side effects. There will no retries even if there is a connection error. I think I will have to live with it until Oracle does some update.